# Google Maps only shows a limited amount (21) of markers from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I've created a google map on my website with functions that dynamically retreives data from a JSON file, then creates markers on the map depending on the data received.

Following the Google's official tutorial on [Google Maps: Working With JSON Objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfjqLmD6Li8), everything works fine except there is a small problem: The map only displays up to about 21 markers while there are at least 1600 entries. The resulting markers are always the same, however they have correct data (markers are in correct position with correct titles for infowindow) Here's a snippet of relevant code:

```
for (var x in dataForm4) {
            var data = dataForm4[x];
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            addMarker (map, data.address, latLng);
     };
  }      //This is where the "initiliaze map" function ends

var infoWindow;
  function addMarker (map, address, latLng){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
    });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    if (typeof infoWindow != 'undefined') infoWindow.close();
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
    content: address
  });

    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

***Notes about code:***

- dataForm4 is the stringified variable of JSON file:

  ```
  <script>
    var dataForm4 = <%- JSON.stringify(form2) %>;
  </script>
  ```
- address is the "title" of each address located inside the JSON file, for using at infowindow
- map variable is defined inside the initialize function

I also have a function where data entered to database is automatically entered to JSON file but that's probably irrelevant.

Sadly, marker clustering is not an option. I've tried using setTimeout() and setInterval() functions but couldn't get it to work properly with my map since I'm new. For reference I'm using a free version of Google's Map API.

Comment: Dang, no wonder "JSON objects" are a growing nuisance if even Google teaches them ...

Comment: My first idea: There is an error in the data, maybe special characters that bother the function. And then the function just stops.  Probably the address.  See what happens if you try this: addMarker (map, 'Hello', latLng)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, after comparing databases, appearently somebody entered some of the data manually, the "lat" variable inside the file was entered as "lat ". Because of the space in the end, google couldn't draw the latitude of addresses. We fixed this earlier but the person responsible forgot to change the data that was entered manually. So a wrong variable was the source of the error.